# Добавление LHDC в AOSP

Tags: android, bluetooth

Я бы очень хотел добавить поддержку LHDC кодека в AOSP прошивку
Как это можно сделать через Magisk?
Я нашёл [этот](https://gitlab.com/savitech-lhdc/savitech-lhdc-codec-aosp-p9.0.0r35/-/tree/lhdc_aosp_p900r35_main) репозиторий, но не могу понять, что именно с ним нужно сделать

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я не знаю, как добавить LHDC в AOSP